# Merge records in SQL Server by start and end times

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have `Reports` table in SQL Server like this:

[image: Report Table]

I need to merge records in this table with same `CallNumber` and `type = Unanswered` and difference `StartDate` one record and `EndDate` another is less than one.
For example of difference operation please see this:

[image: result table]

Result table is like this:

[image: Result]

I execute this query for get records that should be merge but I don't know how merge this records.

```
select t1.CallNumber,t1.id,t1.EndDate,t2.Id,t2.StartDate 
from Reports as t1
left join Reports as t2 on t1.CallNumber = t2.CallNumber and t1.type=t2.type
where 
    t1.EndDate < t2.StartDate
    and DATEDIFF(MINUTE,t1.EndDate,t2.StartDate) < 1
    and t1.type = 'Unanswered'
group by t1.CallNumber,t1.id,t1.EndDate,t2.Id,t2.StartDate
```

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for query that return result table.

Comment: Do you need a query or you need to remove that data permanently?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I need to query that return result table.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "and StartDate one record and EndDate another is less than one.". I'd thought it was that the periods must be continuous with one period ending and the next starting a second later (as in the first two examples) but in your third example, there are 5 second gaps between records. So what is this phrase meant to mean?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I update question please see this again.Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this work for you?

```
declare @t table(ID int
                ,Number int
                ,StartDate datetime
                ,EndDate datetime
                ,Type nvarchar(50)
                );
insert into @t values
 (1 ,2024,'20160102 16:40:00','20160102 16:40:15','Unanswered')
,(2 ,2024,'20160102 16:40:16','20160102 16:40:32','Unanswered')
,(3 ,2060,'20160102 16:40:33','20160102 16:40:48','Answered')
,(4 ,2060,'20160102 16:42:00','20160102 16:42:10','Answered')
,(11,2061,'20160102 16:50:00','20160102 16:50:10','Unanswered')
,(12,2062,'20160102 16:50:14','20160102 16:50:24','Unanswered')
,(13,2061,'20160102 16:50:30','20160102 16:50:44','Unanswered');

select *
from @t t1
    left join @t t2
        on(t1.ID <> t2.ID
            and t1.StartDate > t2.StartDate
            and datediff(s, t2.EndDate, t1.StartDate) < 60  -- DATEDIFF only records boundaries crossed, so 14:34:59 to 14:35:00 would count as 1 minute despite actually being just 1 second.
            and t1.Type = t2.Type
            and t1.Type = 'Unanswered'
            )
where t2.ID is null;
```